# C# VS2017 reference .dll with .props

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, propertysheet

My problem is rather simple, we have a solution mixing `C++` and `C#`, our `C++` project are referring to their dependencies (external libraries) with property sheet attached with the Property Manager window.

As the `C#` project are not shown in the property manager, i still tried to add the .props to the project but can't find a way to make it work, the defined Dll in the .props are still unknown to the project.

Our props are rather simple.

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
<Link>
  <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(External_Repository)\Win64\Static</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
  <AdditionalDependencies>LibA.dll;LibB.dll;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
</Link>
```

The dll are quit heavy, we must save on distant repository and reference them And our architecture help us switch version easily.

```
Folder :
      - Version1.1
          -LibA.dll
          - ...
      - Version2.0
          - LibA.dll
          - ...
```

As such if there is a way to make it work without modifying the `.VCSPROJ` and solely using .props, it'll be wonderful.
How can i make it work? thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [C# reference in .props file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049070/c-sharp-reference-in-props-file)
I found my answer !

```
 <ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="LibA">
  <HintPath>$(External_Repository)\LibA.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Don't forget to make sure your props is well included.